# WMI provider couldn't expose method

Tags: .net, powershell, wmi, provider

I'm writing a WMI provider class. It works well until I add a method with tag [ManagementTask]. What I mean is all of this can be compile and run without any issue. But from powershell, get-wmiobject, I can only see the properties. The method couldn't be found in anyway.

Here is my provider class:

```
//define the provider class.
[InstrumentationClass(InstrumentationType.Instance)]

[ManagementEntity]
public class IPVR_Channel
{

    public string NAME { get; set; }

    public string FAMILY { get; set; }
    public string STATUS { get; set; }
    public string TYPE { get; set; }
    public string URI { get; set; }
    public string VERSION { get; set; }
    public string IP_ADDRESS { get; set; }
    public string PORT { get; set; }


    [ManagementBind]
    public IPVR_Channel()
    {
        NAME = "";
        FAMILY = "";
        STATUS = "";
        TYPE = "";
        URI = "";
        VERSION ="";
        IP_ADDRESS = "";
        PORT = "";
    }
    [ManagementTask]
    public static void set_version()
    {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help. 
James

Comment: What does the command "[<your namespace>.IPVR_Channel] | Get-Member -Static" display, once you have Add-Type'd your assembly in a PowerShell script?

Comment: it shows 2 methods for cmd: gm -static

Comment: Equals and ReferenceEquals, my method is not inside. Thanks.

Comment: PS C:\Users\lliu> gwmi ipvr_channel|gm -static


   TypeName: System.Management.ManagementObject

Name            MemberType Definition
----            ---------- ----------
Equals          Method     static bool Equals(System.Object objA, System.Object objB)
ReferenceEquals Method     static bool ReferenceEquals(System.Object objA, System.Object objB)

Comment: I figured this out. There are two version of WMI extension coexists. One use system.management and another use system.management.instrumentation.

Comment: To expose method, you have to use instrumentation, related configuration/installer and attributes.